# LOOPBACK 4 : Upgrading loopback Cli to latest version, getting BAD REQUEST when a url being Hit with filters and offsets

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

There is a bug in loopback 4 latest CLI version as I just upgraded to the latest LOOPBACK CLI version and tried to HIT a URL from my dashboard and it is saying this is a BAD request.
THE same URL is working with an earlier LOOPBACK CLI version.
URL I am trying to HIT :-

```
http://[::1]:3001/data?filter[limit]=10&filter[offset]=0&filter[order]=id+ASC
```

I checked it again and again with both versions but for the latest one its getting BAD request and for the earlier version it's working.

```
Request URL: http://[::1]:3001/data?filter[limit]=10&filter[offset]=0&filter[order]=id+ASC
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request (from disk cache)
Remote Address: [::1]:3001
```

Anyone knows what is going on here.

Comment: one update on that is if we send URL like this then it is working :-
http://[::1]:3001/data?filter{limit}=10&filter{offset}=0&filter{order}=id%20ASC . This is quite strange.

Comment: Your second example's query string seems to be invalid - It's missing a ampersand (&) before "filter[offset=0]".

Comment: For future reference, this question was also posted here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6140

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I Will wait for the issue to get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `order` filter is expected to be an array.

For example:

```
http://[::1]:3001/data?filter={ "offset": 0, "limit": 100, "order": ["id ASC"] }
```

or:

```
http://[::1]:3001/data?filter[limit]=10&filter[offset]=0&filter[order][0]=id+ASC
```

This is not expected behaviour as the order filter should accept a single string. The issue can be tracked here:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6140